# trigger .each() function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to trigger jquery.each() function?

```
jQuery('img.svg').each(function() {
   console.log("some code");
});
```

Image that have class .svg will create dynamically.

I tried to trigger by

```
$('img.svg').each(); //Not trigger
$('img.svg').trigger('each'); // Not trigger
```

Comment: Keep `jQuery('img.svg').each(function() {
   console.log("some code");
});` is a function and invoke it whenever needed...

Comment: Wait, why would you want to trigger a loop??? Set your each loop inside a function and call this function instead

Answer (score 1):

If class `.svg` is create dynamically. So you need fire `.each` when img will be has `.svg` class. For exmple:

```
function addClass(){
    jQuery('img').addClass('svg');

    jQuery('img.svg').each(function() {
       console.log("some code");
    });
}
```